# Curl in PHP returning wrong results from a REST server

Tags: php, url, rest, browser, curl

I'm trying to get an xml as a result of a rest request, but the behaviour is always weird.

If i try it in a real browser i get always the result asociated to the penultimate request and not the result of the `last/current` request, maybe is a cache problem in the server... , anyway i tried to solve this by just making the request two times in the code, but here the behaviour is even more erratic and it returns results related to previous requests a random number of times and maybe with luck it finally returns the real xml requested (i mean, if i make a requesting loop).

I thought that setting some time between requests with `sleep()` function could solve the problem but nothing.

I also tried to use a browser header to make the curl request... and still the same problem. Why in the browser works at the second time and in curl it doesn't? I must say that the url i request contains empty spaces wich i change with a `'%20'`.. i don't know what else to do!

Here the curl request:

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $uri);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
    $header=array(
        'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.12) Gecko/20101026 Firefox/3.6.12',
        'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
        'Accept-Language: es-es,en;q=0.5',
        'Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate',
        'Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7',
        'Keep-Alive: 115',
        'Connection: keep-alive',
    );
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$header);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: No code, no examples, no clear details = no help.

Comment: i think you didn't read it at all

Comment: Are you sending the appropriate accept headers? 
If you want XML, make sure to set the header to application/xml, etc.

What error response are you getting?
Check the error code.

Comment: i'm not getting any error, i just get an xml that would correspond to an other request previously done!

Comment: The basic curl call as posted in your question works fine as-is. The problem you encounter is specific to your particular use case and we need more code and/or info to help.

Comment: Ok thank you, i'll keep trying

Comment: I would recommend running this query with a diagnostic tool (like Chrome Developer Tools/Firefox Firebug), and analyze the response headers. See if any kind of caching is being enabled. You will also want to do some server side traces (if you have control over the server), in order to determine what it is doing.